# PHP / MySQL Join Query

Tags: php, mysql

does anyone know the best solution to join this query into 1 query rather than 2 as i cannot get it working you see.

```
function fn_order_category_get_order_info($cat_id)
{
    $id1 = db_query("SELECT category_id FROM ?:products_categories WHERE product_id = $cat_id");
    $id2 = db_query("SELECT category FROM ?:category_descriptions WHERE category_id = $id1");
    return $id2;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    pc.category_id,
    cd.category 
FROM
    products_categories pc 
    LEFT JOIN
    category_descriptions cd 
    ON pc.category_id = cd.category_id 
WHERE product_id = $product_id ;
```

Comment: Database error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN category_descriptions cd ON pc.category_id = cd.category_id' at line 2 (1064)
Invalid query: SELECT category_id, category FROM products_categories pc WHERE product_id = 138 LEFT JOIN category_descriptions cd ON pc.category_id = cd.category_id

Comment: @james Sorry, just put the where to the end of the query (edited).

Comment: @styu - it seems that im getting this now: Database error: Column 'category_id' in field list is ambiguous (1052)
Invalid query: SELECT category_id, category FROM cscart_products_categories pc LEFT JOIN cscart_category_descriptions cd ON pc.category_id = cd.category_id WHERE product_id = 138;

Comment: @styu: i have fixed it but its returning th category_id rather than the name assigned to the category_id which would be "category"

Comment: function fn_order_category_get_order_info($product_id)
{
 $result = db_get_field("SELECT pc.category_id, cd.category FROM ?:products_categories pc  LEFT JOIN ?:category_descriptions cd ON pc.category_id = cd.category_id WHERE product_id = $product_id;");
 return $result;
}

Comment: @james Sorry, I wasn't able to test it yesterday. Corrected my answer.